# Multiple instances of static class in same process in C++

Tags: c++, class, static, global-variables

I'm working with a huge project written in C++ (moses, smt translation). The situation is that it stores initial settings in non-static class called "StaticData" with static field "instance" ([StaticData.h](https://github.com/moses-smt/mosesdecoder/blob/master/moses/StaticData.h)). Any other class uses "StaticData.GetInstance()" to access current smt model settings. Now the question is: what would you do to use multiple (at least two) instances of "StaticData" class with minimal code changing? May be there is any way to isolate part of code executing like AppDomain in C#?

Comment: Sounds like `StaticData` is a singleton class.

Comment: Congratulations! You've discovered why singletons are bad.

Comment: @JohnDibling, yes it is. At this moment the only way to load and use two models (means two "StaticData" instances) is to run two processes. And I'm looking for the way to do it within single process.

Comment: The short answer is @NeilKirk is right.  The slightly longer answer is un-singleton-ing that singleton is going to be super difficult and troublesome.

Comment: @JohnDibling, I see. What about  C++ aware solution, some kind of sandboxing code execution ?

Comment: Write another static function "GetSecondInstance"

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
#include <unordered_map>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

class StaticData {
public:
   static StaticData* CreateState(unsigned int id) {
      static unordered_map<unsigned int, unique_ptr<StaticData> > states;
      auto i = states.find(id);
      if (i != states.end()) {
     return i->second.get(); 
      } else {
     states.insert(make_pair<unsigned int, unique_ptr<StaticData> >(
              static_cast<unsigned int>(id), unique_ptr<StaticData>(new StaticData())));
     return CreateState(id);
      }
   }
private:
   StaticData()
   {
   }

};

int main() {
   StaticData* s = StaticData::CreateState(123);
   StaticData* s2 = StaticData::CreateState(124);
   StaticData* s3 = StaticData::CreateState(123);
   if (s != s3) {
      return 1;
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: The problem is there are dozens of other classes uses StaticData.GetInstance - I can't patch them all

Comment: Simple change: `GetInstance() { return CreateState(1); }`